# How to assign a specific color to each taxonomy term in a chart created with the Charts module?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, charts

I have a view with format "Chart" and I'm using Highcharts as my charting library.

In the settings there is a section to choose the colors of the chart.

My content has a field that can have 3 different values. On the chart, the colors are assigned randomly for that field.

Is it possible, using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, or in any other way, to assign a specific color for each of the field values (the field is a taxonomy term)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you must have noticed, [creating charts using the Views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929) of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, you can only select 1 color for each chart.

However, if you would rework your chart to a **Combination chart**, you could set a color for each of the charts. Here are some more details about how I'd create the combination chart (with 1 color for each taxonomy term):

1. Use your current chart display as the parent chart for 3 child charts to be added to it (as explained below). Adapt its chart settings where needed, so that it won't get in the way of the 3 child charts to be added to it. For that, I'd make it a "line chart", possibly with some other refinements like color and label of that chart also.
2. Add a 1st (child) chart display with a views filter that limits the values to only your **1st taxonomy term**, and specify a **1st color** in its chart settings. Use the chart in bullet "1." as its parent chart.
3. Add a 2nd (child) chart display with a views filter that limits the values to only your **2nd taxonomy term**, and specify a **2nd color** in its chart settings. Use the chart in bullet "1." as its parent chart.
4. Add a 3rd (child) chart display with a views filter that limits the values to only your **3rd taxonomy term**, and specify a **3rd** color** in its chart settings. Use the chart in bullet "1." as its parent chart.

Here is an example of a column chart created as a combination chart:

[image]

And this is a variation of it in the format of an area chart (for "total") with 2 line charts:

[image]

As both examples illustrate, for each chart in such combination chart, you can assign any combination of colors ... Which is what this question was about, no?

**Note**: Using this approach, the parent chart in bullet "1." above will avoid that you run into the issue about "holes" in your X-axis data. Refer to my answer to the question about "[How to create a combination chart with the Charts module if some X-axis values are missing?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175174/how-to-create-a-combination-chart-with-the-charts-module-if-some-x-axis-values-a/179414#179414)" for more details on that.